# Checkbox is not visible in ngx-datatable

Tags: node.js, angular, ngx-datatable

Code:  Here is a sample html code. operations is working properly but checkbox is not visible.

```
 <ngx-datatable
              style="width: 90%"
              class="material"
              [rows]="rows"
              [columnMode]="'force'"
              [headerHeight]="50"
              [footerHeight]="50"
              [rowHeight]="'auto'"
              [limit]="5"
              [selected]="selected"
              [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
              [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
              [displayCheck]="displayCheck"
              (activate)="onActivate($event)"
              (select)='onSelect($event)'>
              <ngx-datatable-column
                [width]="30"
                [sortable]="false"
                [canAutoResize]="false"
                [draggable]="false"
                [resizeable]="false"
                [headerCheckboxable]="true"
                [checkboxable]="true">
              </ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Name"></ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Gender"></ngx-datatable-column>
              <ngx-datatable-column name="Company"></ngx-datatable-column>
            </ngx-datatable>
```

import statements is added in src/Style.css

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/material.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css';
```

I m using ngx-datatable version:^11.3.2 , so there is node code like to delete

```
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] { display: none; }
```

Comment: Do you mean this :-  
`<ngx-datatable-column>
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="someFn()"/>
        </ng-template>
    <ngx-datatable-column>`

Comment: yes, but it is not working, an operation is doing good but the checkbox is not visible.

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/952)

Comment: yes, but in our material.css i have code like below to delete. 
  input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] { display: none; }

Comment: please help me to solve this issue

Comment: I have the same issue. Coul you resolved it?

Answer (score -1):

You have a displayCheck function in your ngx-datatable, if it's active you will certainly have hidden checkbox.

[displayCheck]="displayCheck"